# What is the best way to get multiple instances of a program to share information?

Tags: c#

There's information my program has to send from one part to another, such as from `DragEnter` to `GiveFeedback` to change the cursor. This is easily done with a variable as a flag. However – what if the user starts several instances of the program?

One way would be to write information to a file, but it seems best to do as little disk operations as possible. Another way would be to use pipes, but it seems a bit complicated if there are many instances of the program. Is there another way?

Comment: are you asking for a design pattern?

Comment: Why would you need to share information between multiple instances of your application? What data would you share? Can't you provide that information using the [`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.aspx) that's passed to the `DragEnter` event?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek That sounds good. How do you do that? As far as I know, `UseDefaultCursors` is accessible only in `GiveFeedback`, not in `DragEnter`.

Comment: @ispiro: See the documentation for the [`Control.DoDragDrop(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) method.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek From the link you provided (in the example): "The custom cursors are set in the GiveFeedback event handler."

Comment: @ispiro: What does the mouse cursor have to do with anything?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek That is the example I brought in the question for something I need communication for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).

> A memory-mapped file contains the contents of a file in virtual memory. This mapping between a file and memory space enables an application, including multiple processes, to modify the file by reading and writing directly to the memory.

Comment: Great! This seems to be just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
 would probably be how I would set it up... That's if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: "That's if I'm understanding your question correctly." I don't think you are. I'm not aware of MVC being a common solution to IPC.